# the styles generated through javascript are not showing up on the div ( which are generated too )

Tags: javascript

I used a function which generates <div> with class = 'grid' , and added them borderWidth and borderColor using the below function. I do see the changes in the DOM using the  chrome developer tools but I can't see the border width in the box-model.

```
const changeBackground = document.getElementById('backgroundColor');

changeBackground.addEventListener('change', function(e){
    // selects the value of the input color element
    const selectColor = changeBackground.value;
    const grid = document.querySelectorAll('.grid');
    grid.forEach(div => div.style.borderWidth='0.5px')

    if(selectColor === '#000000'){ // checks if the color is black
        console.log(selectColor);
        grid.forEach(div => div.style.borderColor='white');
        container.style.backgroundColor = selectColor;
     }else {
        grid.forEach(div => div.style.borderColor='#000000');

        // assign the selected color to the container
        container.style.backgroundColor = selectColor;
}
})
```

I was expecting the as the container changes its colour to black the divs which are appended change their individual borderWidth and borderColor accordingly so its more visible.

Comment: how about you add the html and any css to the question, enough to demonstrate what it is you think you're doing

Comment: Nah, I figured it I was supposed to add the `.style.borderStyle = 'solid' ` that did the work, I'm dumb!